# Would there be issues with applying --record-only option with svn merge multiple times?

Tags: svn, merge

Would there be issues with SVN mergeinfo and/or SVN in general if one keeps applying 
`svn merge --record-only` on a revision number repeatedly and commit in a 
`svn merge --record-only` followed by `svn commit` followed by `svn merge --record-only` followed by `svn commit` and the next cycle begins? It's not an infinite loop svn merge; it would stop at some point.